# How to Fix Collapsing Top and Bottom Margins?

Tags: css, margin

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to understand how to fix the following line from not working for top and bottom margins. It works for side margins just fine, however:

```
.contents {
    ...
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LCTeU/

How do I fix this?

Edit:

I've also tried padding the container instead, and that just expands the container to maximum size (why?):

```
.container {
    ...
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think you might be confusing margins with padding. Padding is on the inside, margins are on the outside. See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/padding

Comment: The fiddle you provided does not collapse the margins

Comment: More tips: CSS comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`.

Comment: Quick tip, `margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;` = `margin: 10px;`

Comment: @KevinBowersox That fiddle *does* collapse margins. The `<h2>` and `<article>` margins are collapsed. This is how the OP wanted it to look like: http://jsfiddle.net/LCTeU/2/ (note: I added `overflow:hidden` to `<article>` to achieve this effect, another method would be adding `border: 1px solid transparent;`, both have side effects).

Comment: Perhaps you want margin *and* padding?

Comment: Dunno why I got the down votes. Just trying to learn. Can someone please give me an example? I've spent literally hours on this.

Comment: @RobW Whoops I was looking at the articles, I got confused since the post does not match the fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based off of the fiddle you provided.

I think your approach is incorrect in that your applying a margin to the `article` to space it within the parent `div` tag.  It is better to use padding in this case, since your attempting to separate the content from its outside border.  So apply:

```
article {
  //display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

This will cause the `article` tags to increase in size, however the borders of the container `div` elements will now be touching.  To create space between elements a `margin` is applied.

```
.rounded-box {
  background-color: #959392;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/LCTeU/4/

So just to recap, when you want to create space between two elements use `margin`.  When you want to create space between an element and its border (or you want an element to be surrounded by whitespace) use `padding`.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thank you so much! Can you explain one more thing please? Why do the div elements touch when padding is added?

Comment: Because no margin was supplied.  In your first example this would have occurred, however you specified `clear:both` on the article.  See http://jsfiddle.net/LCTeU/5/ which removes the clear

Comment: Disregard the thing about clear, its because there were no margins to separate the elements.

Answer (score 12):

Use `overflow:auto` on any of the elements that are involved with the collapse. For example:

```
article {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LCTeU/3/)**

Comment: How does this answer compare to the answer @KevinBowersox gives above? This is fewer lines, but it seems better to me to specify margin and padding, than it does to use the overflow property, since it's not immediately clear to me how this works.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain further. The way this works has to do with the block formatting context. See http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context.

Answer (score 4):

I found a fix that does not require a padding, and does not require changing the `overflow` of the container element:

```
article:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The idea being that we add another element at the bottom that disrupts the collapsing margin, without affecting the height or padding.

Answer (score 0):

As per the fix that Erik Rothoff suggested, which does not seem to work in Safari, first I tried the following:

```
article:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This *does* work in Safari but takes up space which I could not get rid off, messing up the grid so much that I would need to change margins.

Then I decided to combine the two by doing the following:

```
article:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

This works in Safari, has an acceptable height of 1px which is negated by the negative margin top.